# Diferenças entre traits e namespace quanto ao carregamento

Tags: php, namespace, trait

Usando *namespace* o carregamento do arquivo se faz no momento em que se usa algum método `say`, se não invocar nada da classe o arquivo não será carregado.

```
use World;
class Hello {
    World::say()
}
```

Usando *trait* mesmo sem invocar método ou propriedade o arquivo é carregado no momento do *use*.

```
class Hello {
    use world;
}
```

---

Estou "iniciando" no *traits*, minha dúvida é sobre esse comportamento tão diferente do *namespace*. Porque o fato de declara o *USE* faz o carregamento do arquivo, enquanto *namespace* não?

Essa é uma característica própria de *traits* ou há alguma configuração que possa definir o carregamento do *traits* apenas quando algo for invocado?

Comment: Também não conheço muito do assunto em PHP mas se for igual a outras linguagens, os dois conceitos são tão distintos que não sei se dá para comparar.

Comment: Não é comparar o funcionamento, apenas o motivo de declarar o *use* no trait faz o carregamento do arquivo no ato, enquanto com namespace só quando usada a classe.

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar responder.

Comment: Basicamente é o que o @bigown disse na resposta dele. Um `use` não tem nada a ver com outro.  Um outro exemplo é o uso de uma `function`, que na declaração de métodos tem um papel e dentro de uma função anônima tem comportamento diferente

Comment: Verdade, o *use* usado em ambos os casos me fez esperar um comportamento igual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Namespaces* são usados para agrupar, encapsular funcionalidades. É usado basicamente para evitar conflito de nomes. Ele funciona como um sobrenome para seus membros, desta forma você pode ter dois `João`s em sua aplicação desde que um seja `Silva` e o outro `Oliveira`.

Neste caso o `use` serve para indicar apenas que esta família está disponível para uso, ou seja, todos seus membros estão acessíveis. Mas a carga dos membros ocorrerão apenas sob demanda, afinal a família está disponível para ser chamada, mas se você não precisa de um membro, não tem porque ele estar presente fisicamente. Ele serve mais como um indicativo para o interpretador saber que os membros de um *namespace* **podem** ser usados.

Já o *trait* existe para possibilitar o reuso de código em classes que só permitem herança simples. É uma forma de adicionar comportamento pré-definido a uma classe.

Neste caso o `use` tem propósito completamente diferente, ele indica para a classe que ela deve incluir entre seus membros todos os membros do *trait* especificado. O *trait* é parte integrante da classe, sem ele a classe não estaria completa, o conteúdo do *trait* é fundamental para a classe funcionar, não é opcional. Mesmo que uma instância não chame nenhum membro do *trait* ele precisa estar na classe para completá-la, você não pode ter classes "mancas".

Estas duas funcionalidades compartilham essencialmente a mesma sintaxe para a inclusão de código externo mas possuem semânticas completamente diferentes e são conceitualmente distantes. Não há relação entre seu uso a não ser o fato que obviamente, por acaso, um *trait* pode ser membro de um *namespace*.

Comment: Entendi, acho que o que me levou à duvida foi o uso da mesma palavra reservada *use*. Obrigado

Comment: Algum usuário achou que eu escrevi bobagem e negativou a resposta, pena que ele não vai ajudar as pessoas sobre o que está errado.

Comment: Acharam que eu também escrevi bobagem, mas não tem a ver com o conteúdo certo ou errado.