# Palavra chave "use" no php

Tags: php

Estava utilizando uma api quando eu me deparo com o seguinte código:

```
$push->on('incoming', function (\InstagramAPI\Push\Notification $push) use ($ig, $socket) {
    ...
});
```

Eu percebi que a palavra "use" serve para utilizar determinada variável dentro do escopo daquela função interna, mas foi apenas uma conclusão que tirei, o que eu queria saber é, se é simplesmente isso e ponto final ou se há algo a mais.

Quando eu pesquiso por 'use' em php só aparece sobre o 'use' para importar classes, como por exemplo:

```
use React\EventLoop\Timer\TimerInterface;
```

O mais proximo que cheguei da resposta foi isso:

> use doesn't include anything. It just imports the specified namespace
>   (or class) to the current scope

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it

Mas fala apenas sobre classes e namespace nada sobre variaveis, queria saber mais sobre esta palavra 'use', pois estou com algumas dificuldades para utilizar esta api e ela utiliza bastante deste recurso e não quero esta fazendo algo errado por não saber utilizar o recurso.

Comment: Acho que a resposta dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172133/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-comando-use-e-qual-%C3%A9-a-sua-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-anonimas) pode esclarecer sua dúvida.

Comment: Também pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32467/101

Comment: Como você pode ver nos links que indicaram acima, existem dois tipos de `use` no php. Um é para importar namespaces, e outro para capturar variáveis de outro escopo (uma implementação de closures). O seu exemplo é desse segundo tipo.

Comment: Então é isso, o 'use' neste caso vai deixar acessível a variável.

Comment: A mensagem *use doesn't include anything. It just imports the specified namespace (or class) to the current scope* creio que foi respondida em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151487/namespaces-e-use-quando-usar-e-para-que-servem/151492#151492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use para escopo em função anônimas

Estamos usando aqui uma função anônima

```
$push->on('incoming', function (\InstagramAPI\Push\Notification $push) use ($ig, $socket) {
    ...
});
```

Quando utilizamos a palavras "use" em um função anônima como no exemplo acima, a variável passa para o escopo da função anônima, porem não como referencia, caso necessário passar como referencia basta fazer como o exemplo abaixo

```
$push->on('incoming', function (\InstagramAPI\Push\Notification &$push) use ($ig, $socket) {
    ...
});
```

Assim qualquer alteração na variável "$push" será refletida externamente.

## Use em Namespace

```
use React\EventLoop\Timer\TimerInterface;
```

Quando utilizamos o "use" como namespace, informamos de onde ele pertence, como no exemplo acima, TimerInterface esta dentro de Timer que por sua vez esta dentro de EventLoop e por fim dentro de React.

E para que isso server? Imagine que exista um outro "TimerInterface", mas ele vai pertencer a outro lugar por exemplo

```
use LugarMagico\TimerInterface;
```

Porem se utilizamos os dois TimerInterface no mesmo lugar desta forma

```
use React\EventLoop\Timer\TimerInterface;
use LugarMagico\TimerInterface;

$timer = new TimerInterface();
```

Não será possível já que como que o php saberá qual TimerInterface é o que estou chamando, e para resolver isso é simples basta fazer o seguinte

```
use React\EventLoop\Timer\TimerInterface;
use LugarMagico\TimerInterface as TimerMagico;

$timer = new TimerInterface();
$timerMagico= new TimerMagico();
```

Desta forma eu atribuo um apelido, assim o php saberá qual estou chamando

## fontes

Melhorei a minha resposta graças ao [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento), respondi de acordo com a minha interpretação, porem o Guilherme respondeu com maestria nos seguintes links abaixo.

[Namespaces e Use quando usar e para que servem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151487/namespaces-e-use-quando-usar-e-para-que-servem/151492#151492)

[Qual é a finalidade do comando "use" e qual é a sua relação com funções anonimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172133/qual-%c3%a9-a-finalidade-do-comando-use-e-qual-%c3%a9-a-sua-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-anonimas/172134#172134)

Comment: Caro Wictor o `use` com namespaces não tem nada haver com escopo. O use em classes é totalmente diferente do use em Closures ... O `use`em classes não faz "nada", mesmo com spl, no PHP ele serve somente para criar apelidos, como expliquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151487/namespaces-e-use-quando-usar-e-para-que-servem/151492#151492 ... E sobre o use em closures, expliquei aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172134/3635 .. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado, @GuilhermeNascimento, editei a pergunta :)